# Syntax to compare check box value with a boolean column in a table in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to compare a yes/no boolean field with a check box value on a form in a query. Can someone please tell me the syntax of the expression to compare these values in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unbound checkbox, it is possible for it to have a null value, unlike a table boolean (Yes/No), which must be either True or False (Yes or No, -1 or 0). You can use this to skip the check if it is not completed.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.CheckBox) Then
   sWhere = " And MyYesNo=" & Me.CheckBox
End If
```

For a query, you can say:

```
SELECT AYesNo
FROM Table1 
WHERE AYesNo Like
  IIf(IsNull([forms]![myform]![CheckBox]),"*",[forms]![myform]![CheckBox])
```

Comment: Should this be used in the query? I need something that I can use in the query. For example, I've used the calculation shown below for comparing text values in a column and in the form:

[field] = [Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form] or [Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form] is null

Comment: You can use something like the second example in a query.

Comment: Oh thank you sooo much! I tweaked your code a little bit and it worked fine!